# Is there a reason some of VIM's motion commands are restricted to one line?

Tags: vim

I'm beginning to learn VIM (I've downloaded an emulator plugin for my IDE) and unsurprisingly it's making me irritated and extremely slow. That is all fine and I realize it's a phaze everyone goes through.

However this one feature is quite frustrating - being unable to jump to the next line via <kbd>l</kbd>, previous with <kbd>h</kbd> or search more than one line with <kbd>f</kbd>.

Is there a valid, typing speed enhancing reason for this?

Comment: By any chance it wouldn'be be ViEmu we're talking about here?

Comment: No, I'm using IdeaVIM for PHP Storm.

Comment: +1 for understanding `vim` can be hard at first.

Comment: Note that motion commands also support the "distance" you want to move, e.g. try typing `50l` or `10k`.

Comment: There are solutions for making f, F, t, T multiline here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925230/vim-multiline-f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `h` and `l` wrap lines by adding `h` and `l` to the `whichwrap` option (`:he whichwrap`), although for the sake of compatibility with scripts and macros that don't expect `h` and `l` to wrap, you might want to avoid adding them, and add the `<` and `>` options instead (which allow the left and right arrow keys to wrap).

As for `f` (and `F` and `t` and `T`), they're just really not meant to do that, but you can use `/` and `?` as movements -- `d/foo<Enter>` to delete everything between here and a following "foo" (whether it's on this line or a later one).

Comment: *>As for f (and F and t and T), they're just really not meant to do that...* But is there reason they aren't?

Comment: Two reasons. The first, philosophical one: because they're short-range movements. Since they only search for a single letter, they get less useful and more error-prone the further you want t ogo, and so it's not worth using them over multiple lines. The second, pragmatic one: because that's how it worked 35 years ago when vi was a descendant of a line-based editor, and since other commands exist that *can* do the same thing across lines, it wasn't seen as necessary to break compatibility for `f` and friends.