# Using vim's f command over multiple lines

Tags: vim

Anyone knows how to quickly find the next occurrence of a character (like the f command) but multi-line? I.e. to quickly jump to the next occurrence of some character in a file?

Comment: I [summarised some alternatives here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/expand-f-and-t-motion-to-next-lines#4525), including one I helped to write which *flashes counts* on the screen!

Comment: I was struggling with this too. Here's where I'm at after reviewing this post: If it's a line away it's likely cheaper or equivalent to just `jk` then `f{char}`. If it's more than a line away it's cheaper to use `/`. You could also jump to the line then `f` to it (`#G` `f{char}`).

Answer (score 52):

Isn't that what "/" does?

If you're looking for the next "x" then do /x while in command mode.

Then you can hit "n" to advance to the next x, and then the next x, etc.

There are lots of vim [cheat sheets](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html) out there with all kinds of tips.

Comment: Thanks! I actually knew of / and was wondering if you know of a quicker way (sorry I didn't say that in the original question). Instead of typing / and then needing to type <enter> is there a single key way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: hmm... "fx" is two keystrokes.  hitting "/x<enter>" is three keystrokes.  after the first match, you can advance to subsequent hits with one more keystroke in both cases.  who besides a vi(m) user could be upset at such inefficiency :)  Are you always searching for the same character, or type of character?  If so there may be  solution for you, especially if it is programming related, like "move to the next curly brace"

Comment: @Koko - the answer is, yes, there is one character to find the next occurrence, the letter 'n'.  And that is included in the answer.

Comment: There is a significant difference that you don't cover in your answer, `dfx` will delete up to, and including `x`. On the other hand `d/x<enter>` will delete up to, but not including, `x`.

Answer (score 13):

There's an example of redefining `f` to ignore case in the 'eval.txt' help file.

```
:h eval.txt
```

(search for "ignore case" a couple times)

We can modify that to do what you want.  Add the following function to your `~/.vimrc` file or better yet, create a plugin file: `~/.vim/plugin/find-char.vim` (create the directories if you do not already have them).

```
function FindChar()
    let c = nr2char( getchar() )
    let match = search('\V' . c)
endfunction
```

---

Then, in your `~/.vimrc` add the following line:

```
nmap f :call FindChar()<CR>
```

Now, `f` should work like you want it to.

BTW, this was tested with Vim 7.2 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: this will not work if you are searching for `$`, `\`, `^` or `/` among others (also maybe star, interrogation mark, etc. You could `let command = "normal! /\V" . c . "^M"`. Still this won't work for backslash.

Comment: @Benoit: Ahh, special characters, I should have known better.  I've updated the response.

Comment: You could skip the if statement if you just prepend every search pattern with '\V' --  function FindChar()
    let c = nr2char( getchar() )
    let match = search('\V' . c)
endfunction

Comment: If you want the "last search" to be set to the character, add this to the function:  call setreg("/", c)  -- this way, the "n" and "p" commands are useful thereafter.

Comment: You may also want to write the function and mappings so that the F, t, and T commands are similarly affected.

Answer (score 11):

Christian Brabandt's [ft_improved plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3877) extends the built-in `f` / `t` commands to search in following lines, too.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that out.  But I ended up using http://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic (which can work with `.` commands if you also install http://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat ).  9 months no complaints!

Comment: At least for me, both improvedft and vim-fanfingtastic both fail to handle something like `2f,` which one might expect to jump the cursor to the comma after next. The former plugin does nothing given this sequence, whereas the latter will simply jump one comma ahead, instead of two.

Answer (score 7):

Having wanted to know exactly the same thing I looked through the answers here. None of are exactly what I wanted so I cobbled together a few of them.

q335's answer was the closest because it handles omaps properly which is necessary to do something like `dt}` (delete everything up to, but not including the next curly brace) but Curt's answer handles special character searching and uses a single function which to me is much more preferable so I'm not adding too much to my .vimrc

Here is my result:

```
"Makes f and t work across multiple lines
nmap <silent> f :call FindChar(0, 0, 0)<cr>
omap <silent> f :call FindChar(0, 1, 0)<cr>
nmap <silent> F :call FindChar(1, 0, 0)<cr>
omap <silent> F :call FindChar(1, 1, 0)<cr>
nmap <silent> t :call FindChar(0, 0, 1)<cr>
omap <silent> t :call FindChar(0, 0, 0)<cr>
nmap <silent> T :call FindChar(1, 0, 1)<cr>
omap <silent> T :call FindChar(1, 0, 0)<cr>

"Functions
fun! FindChar(back, inclusive, exclusive)
  let flag = 'W' 
  if a:back
    let flag = 'Wb'
  endif
  if search('\V' . nr2char(getchar()), flag)
    if a:inclusive
      norm! l
    endif
    if a:exclusive
      norm! h
    endif
  endif
endfun
```

Comment: Seemed to work ok, but it did not retain the searched char for use by `;` and `,`

Comment: Motion to closing curly brace: ]} - if you want to delete: d]} - works for parens as well ]) - motion to opening braces is [{

Comment: Does not work for me when prefixed with a number, e.g. `c2fa` changes up to the _first_ `a`.

Answer (score 5):

Aaaa, vimscript. It takes about 2 years to write 20 lines well :D. Here is the latest, sleekest version: works for ALL modes: visual, operator pending, normal.

```
let prvft='f'
let prvftc=32
fun! MLvF(c,...)
    let [g:prvftc,g:prvft]=[a:c,a:0? 'f':'F']
    let pos=searchpos('\C\V'.nr2char(g:prvftc),'bW')
    call setpos("'x", pos==[0,0]? [0,line('.'),col('.'),0] : [0,pos[0],pos[1],0])
    return "`x"
endfun
fun! MLvf(c,...)
    let [g:prvftc,g:prvft]=[a:c,a:0? 'F':'f']
    let pos=searchpos('\C\V'.nr2char(g:prvftc).(mode(1)=='no'? '\zs' : ''),'W')
    call setpos("'x", pos==[0,0]? [0,line('.'),col('.'),0] : [0,pos[0],pos[1],0])
    return "`x"
endfun
fun! MLvT(c,...)
    let [g:prvftc,g:prvft]=[a:c,a:0? 't':'T']
    let pos=searchpos('\C\V'.nr2char(g:prvftc).'\zs','bW')
    call setpos("'x", pos==[0,0]? [0,line('.'),col('.'),0] : [0,pos[0],pos[1],0])
    return "`x"
endfun
fun! MLvt(c,...)
    let [g:prvftc,g:prvft]=[a:c,a:0? 'T':'t']
    let pos=searchpos('\C\V\_.'.(mode(1)=='no'? '\zs' : '').nr2char(g:prvftc),'W')
    call setpos("'x", pos==[0,0]? [0,line('.'),col('.'),0] : [0,pos[0],pos[1],0])
    return "`x"
endfun
no <expr> F MLvF(getchar())
no <expr> f MLvf(getchar())
no <expr> T MLvT(getchar())
no <expr> t MLvt(getchar())
no <expr> ; MLv{prvft}(prvftc)
no <expr> , MLv{prvft<#'Z'? tolower(prvft) : toupper(prvft)}(prvftc,1)
```

Or the super garbled:

```
let [pvft,pvftc]=[1,32]
fun! Multift(x,c,i)
    let [g:pvftc,g:pvft]=[a:c,a:i]
    let pos=searchpos((a:x==2? mode(1)=='no'? '\C\V\_.\zs' : '\C\V\_.' : '\C\V').(a:x==1 && mode(1)=='no' || a:x==-2? nr2char(g:pvftc).'\zs' : nr2char(g:pvftc)),a:x<0? 'bW':'W')
    call setpos("'x", pos[0]? [0,pos[0],pos[1],0] : [0,line('.'),col('.'),0]) 
    return "`x"
endfun
no <expr> F Multift(-1,getchar(),-1)
no <expr> f Multift(1,getchar(),1)
no <expr> T Multift(-2,getchar(),-2)
no <expr> t Multift(2,getchar(),2)
no <expr> ; Multift(pvft,pvftc,pvft)
no <expr> , Multift(-pvft,pvftc,pvft)
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach to this problem is to use the [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plugin.

This lets you use motions such as `f` across the entire visible window of text. You trigger the plugin, then enter `f` and the character you are looking for. It highlights each position that the character appears on screen in a highlight color (e.g. red), and shows the position using a letter (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, ...). You simply press the letter corresponding to the position you wish to jump to.

The plugin's README on Github includes an animation that visually demonstrates how it works.

Answer (score 4):

The most reasonable way of doing this at the moment is hidden in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925230/using-vims-f-command-over-multiple-lines#comment33598321_15173969).

You just have to install two plugins: [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) and [vim-fanfingtastic](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic).

Personally, I use [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) to manage my vim plugins.

So this is the way you can make `f`, `F`, etc. work as desired:

1. Install Vundle.
2. Add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

   ```
   Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
   Plugin 'dahu/vim-fanfingtastic'
   ```
3. Run `$ vim +PluginInstall +qall` in your shell.
4. Voila!

Answer (score 2):

You could make a mapping to go to the next character under the cursor:

```
:map f yl/\V<c-r>"<c-m>
```

the \V will make sure symbols are matched literally.

Also, you may want to look at the `*` and `#` commands, which are already defined for you, although they might not be what you want.