# Using the 'f' command in vim to search more than just the current line

Tags: vim

I know that philosophically the `f`/`F` command is used to search through the current line. However, other than `[LINE]G` `f`, what would be the best way to jump to somewhere else in the file in the style of the `f` command?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925230/vim-multiline-f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to you `~/.vimrc`

```
set incsearch
```

to activate incremental search and use `/foo<CR>` to search forward or `?bar<CR>` to search backward.

Note that, like `fFtT`, `/?` can also be very useful as motions for `dcsv`.

If you don't mind using a plugin, there are a bunch of them designed around the idea of multi-dimensional `fFtT` like [this one](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic). Take a look around vim.org.

Comment: 'dcsv' <-- what is dcsv?

Comment: Operators `d`, `c`, `s`,  `v`.

Comment: @romainl aha moment here ! never used dcsv on fFtT, so gotta try ? and /

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the vim plugin **EasyMotion**,

- [github repo](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion)
- [vim online](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526)

`<Leader>f<char>` will search forward from current line to the end of current window.
`<Leader>F<char>` will search backward from current line to the start of current window.

for all usage `:help easymotion.txt`

Comment: Thanks for this, +1. However, I would prefer a non-plugin solution (as I don't want to depend on a plugin and get used to it). If I don't get a non-plugin solution I'll accept yours.

Comment: In a non-plugin way, type `/`(search forward) or `?`(search backward) then the search pattern. Use `n` to repeat the last search,use `N` to repeat the last search in the opposite direction.   By the way, easymotion is easy to use because it is analogous to standard Vim motion.

Answer (score 1):

Christian Brabandt's [ft_improved plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3877) extends the built-in `f` / `t` commands to search in following lines, too.