# How to avoid ; repeat command in vim highlighting text?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Like most, i have enabled `hlsearch` in vimrc.
so, all my text searches are highlighted.
But, when i use `'f'` command to move to a letter and use `';'` command to repeat, vim highlights all the occurrences of the character overriding my previous text search.

how can i make vim just move to the character without interfering with my text search keyword?

Comment: This is not standard behavior. Are you sure you don't have some plugin or mapping that is misbehaving.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks for pointing out. I verified my plugins and found ft_improved plugin is the causing this behaviour. ft_improved plugin helps to extend f,t commands over multiple lines which is useful to me. Can you suggest any other plugin similar to ft_improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've likely found a bug in the ft_improved plugin; you should report that to the plugin's issue tracker.

Alternatively, you can also check out an alternative; [Extended-FT](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4726) and [Fan,FingTastic](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic) are two. Also, [using vims f command over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925230/using-vims-f-command-over-multiple-lines) has some light-weight implementations in the answers.

Comment: Extended-FT works as expected. Thanks :) . I will report this bug to ft_improved plugin tracker.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!