# Jump to char on a subsequent line

Tags: vim

I was editing part of my `.vimrc` and wanted to add a space after each `"` in the comments.

```
if has("gui_running")
    :set guioptions-=T      "remove toolbar
    :set guioptions-=r      "remove right-hand scroll bar
    :set guioptions-=L      "remove left-hand scroll bar
endif
```

I wanted a somewhat clever way to do this so on the first line inside the if I started typing `f"a␣<Esc>`. With this my `.` command now had `a␣<Esc>` in it. Good.

I thought "now I need only type `;.` a bunch of times and this will do the work." 
What I was not expecting was that the `;` command only worked on the current line, meaning that I had to type at least `j;.` each time.

So my question is: is there another set of commands other than `f`, `;` and `,` that will jump to a character even if it is on a subsequent (or preceding) line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using vim's f command over multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925230/using-vims-f-command-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: @glts I looked this up before I asked but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the required char(") using `/"` and then jump to it using `n`(in the forward direction) or `N`(in the backward direction)
and then hit `.` to repeat the substitution.

If you want to replace all occurances of `"` with `"␣`, an easier way would be the following command

```
:%s/"/"␣/g
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about that too. But I rejected the idea because I was incredulous that `f` and `;` could not do this. `/"<CR>` only adds one keystroke overhead so I guess I should have used that. Substitute would work too if I specified a range. I will see if anyone comes with another interesting option. Otherwise I will eventually accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that extend the `f` / `t` commands beyond the current line, for example [ft_improved](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3877).