# "dt" motion in Vim working with mutiple lines

Tags: vim, text-editor

I very often use `dt-some_character` motion in Vim, to delete every character upto `some_character`. However, it works only for a single line.

Is there any analogue that would work for multiple lines?

Comment: I recommend EasyMotion plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Using vim's f command over multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3925230/438329). Note: there have been more plugins that been made since the time of this last post. Like [EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion), [vim-seek](https://github.com/goldfeld/vim-seek), and [sneak.vim](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) to name a few.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `d/some-character<CR>` (e.g `d/e` then Enter to delete up to the next 'e').

Note however that this **will** modify the `last-search register` (`"/`).

**Edit** :

The counterpart to `F` is `?` (search backwards) (`d?X` is inclusive, so no `dT`).

Comment: Is there any way to make it work without `<CR>`, like `dt` does?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and I don't think it's doable/desirable since you may want to enter more than 1 letter (ie `d/abc<CR>` to delete up to the next occurence of `abc`, skipping occurences of `a` and `ab`). You might want to look into plugins, though I don't know any that do this.

Comment: Actually, a counterpart to `dTX` would be `d?X?e+1`. See `:help search-offset`.

Answer (score 5):

There are several *plugins* that extend the built-in `f` / `t` motions to cover multiple lines:

- [ft_improved](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3877)
- [fanfingtastic](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic)

Another one that goes into the same direction, but via a different approach:

- [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526)

Answer (score 2):

As said by ***Marth*** you could use the `d/a_pattern_to_be_searched` command. Since you have made a search, then you could use the `n` (next search result) [or the `N` (previous search result)] command in combination with delete.

Let's see an example, suppose you have this lines:

```
This is a first line - 01
This is a new line - 02
And this is the last line - 03
```

With the cursor on the **i** of **is** on the first line, giving `d/line` you'll get:

```
This line - 01
This is a new line - 02
And this is the last line - 03
```

Now if you give to vim the `dn` command, you'll get:

```
This line - 02
And this is the last line - 03
```

Also remember that you could use a **count** argument with the motion, so if you give the `d3/line` command instead of `d/line` in the above example, you'll get:

```
This line - 03
```

(we have said to vim: *delete up to the third occurrence of "line"*)

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to make the same operation on sevral line**:

You may use `j.` and/or a macro

for instance to delete until the character '7' on 2 lines (without macro):

```
df7j.
```

to delete until the character '7' on `<n>` lines, you need to record a macro:

```
qqdf7j<Esc><n>@q
```

**If you want to delete from the current position until the character 7 on multiple lines** (it will also delete the 7 character):

```
v/7<Esc>x
```

Comment: This does not work as intended. If `df7` does not find character `7` on current line it stops and `j.` does nothing (and even if it did then it would not delete the previous line). My understanding of the question is "How to use `dta` to delete up to the first occurence of `a` when `a` does not appear on current line."

Comment: In the last version of vim (7.4.712) `df7` would search the next 7 on the current line (not going backward). `j` just go at the next line. `.` repeat the last action. And if fact if the question is how to delete the first occurrence of a character which is not on the current line I am totally wrong.