# Go to next character even if on a later row?

Tags: vim

I know I can do `f{` to find the next `{` on the same row, but can I have vim search for the character not until the end of the line but rather the end of the file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925230/using-vims-f-command-over-multiple-lines `/` seems to be what you need. Speaking for myself I normally only use that as a 'find' but it should also work as a 'go to next instance of character', albeit with an additional key press